# Enable CORS in a Backbone client with a Flask server

Tags: backbone.js, flask, cors

I want to do cross domain requests between my backbone app at 127.0.0.1 and and my Flask server at 127.0.0.1:5000. Before I switched to a Backbone I had an Ember.js app and I had the same problem. But I got it working by adding this in my Flask app:

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(data):
    response = make_response(data)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost'
    return response
```

and configure the Ember `RESTAdapter` this way:

```
adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({ 
    url : 'http://127.0.0.1:5000',
    // In order to allow cross domain requests

    ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
       jQuery.ajax(url)
    }
  })
});
```

But this does not work with my Backbone application.

> `XMLHttpRequest` cannot load `http://127.0.0.1:5000/files`.
>   Request header field `Content-Type` is not allowed by `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

I guess I've to change some settings on the client side. But I don't know what.
What do I've to do so that I am able to to do cross domain requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what worked for me.

http://flask-cors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

$ pip install -U flask-cors

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.cors import CORS, cross_origin
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

@app.route("/")
@cross_origin()
def helloWorld():
  return "Hello, cross-origin-world!"
```

Comment: I recently stumbled upon this plugin and this is a nicer more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by adding

`response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "Origin, X-Requested-With,Content-Type, Accept"` to the `after_request()` method.

Answer (score 0):

For development you can:

- Use Chrome extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi
- Start chrome in unsecured mode - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177718/1104483

Or just set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*`

Comment: Modifying the browser is not an option for production. And I've set the `Acces-Control-Allow-Origin` header already and it did not work.

Comment: Dude, I have added `For development` special for you. Where have you found `production`?